# starting 12c managed server with Nodemanager in 12C giving java.io.IOException

Tags: weblogic12c

I am in the process of upgrading application env from weblogic 9.2 to 12C.

I have nodemanager running in 9.2 env. When managed server is started with nodemanager; no files/dirs are created under domainhome/servers/managed_home/data(nodemanager).

However after upgrading to 12C(separate installation of wls and nodemanager) starting 12C managed server with 12c nodemanager creates files/dir at above location.

I'm not able to figure out why. Any help/thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Is it causing a problem? What is the question? Normally when you start a managed server, weblogic will download the embedded ldap to `<domain>/servers/<server name>/data/ldap` and nodemanager start params to `data/nodemanager`

Comment: start asking questions when things go wrong.